# Problem with overloading input operator in c++

Tags: c++, input, overloading

I started to learn C++ recently and i ran into this trouble with using overloaded input operator >>.

I am writing a class to describe a Complex number.
My problem is: If i put my main() in the Complex.cpp, my program run normally. But if i create a new file main.cpp and put my main() there i ran into error.

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream') and 'Complex')
>
> candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream') to 'std::istream *' (aka 'basic_istream *') for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
>
> (There are a lots more error bellow but they point to istream so i don't think that is the problem)

This is my header file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#endif // HEADER_H

class Complex
{
public:
    double _real;
    double _imag;

public:
    Complex(double, double);
    double getReal() const;
    double getImag() const;
    void setReal(double);

public:
    Complex operator=(const Complex&);
    Complex * operator+(const Complex&);
    Complex * operator+(const double&);
    friend Complex * operator+(const double&, const Complex&);
    Complex * operator++();
    Complex * operator++(int);
    Complex * operator--();
    Complex * operator--(int);
    operator double() const;
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream*, const Complex&);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream*, Complex&);
};
```

And i created Complex.cpp to identify the function:

```
#include "Complex.h"

using namespace std;

Complex::Complex(double a, double b)
{
    this->_real = a;
    this->_imag = b;
}

double Complex::getReal() const{...}

void Complex::setReal(double x){...}

double Complex::getImag() const{...}

Complex Complex::operator=(const Complex& other){...}

Complex * Complex::operator+(const Complex& other){...}

Complex * Complex::operator+(const double &other){...}

Complex * operator+(const double &first, const Complex &second){...}

Complex * Complex::operator++(){...}

Complex * Complex::operator++(int){...}

Complex * Complex::operator--(){...}

Complex * Complex::operator--(int){...}

Complex::operator double() const{...}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Complex &comp)
{
    output << comp._real << " + " << comp._imag << "i";
    return output;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &input, Complex &comp)
{
    input >> comp._real >> comp._imag;
    return input;
}
```

This is my main:

```
#include "Complex.h"

int main()
{
    Complex com4(0,0);
    cout << "Input Complex: ";
    cin >> com4;
    cout << com4 <<endl;
}
```

Comment: `ostream*` -> `ostream&`, `istream*` -> `istream&`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. For questions like yours, a [mcve] is also mantadory.

Comment: Er... what's with all those pointers? Look at the standard complex number class for an idea what the method signatures should be.

Comment: Complex * operator++(); All these lines of code edit them. they should be Complex & operator++(); . They should return reference.

Comment: thank @tkausl, i can't believe i made that mistake. this is embarrassing

Answer (score 0):

You declared io operators with pointers (which is wrong)

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream*, const Complex&);
friend istream &operator>>(istream*, Complex&);
```

but implemented it correctly with references.

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Complex&) {...}
friend istream &operator>>(istream&, Complex&) {...}
```

When you have your `main()` in Complex.cpp, the compiler can see those correct implementations (that are not defined in any header).

If you have your `main()` somewhere else, the compiler can only see the declarations in the header, which have the wrong signature.

Solution will be to fix the declarations of `operator<<` and `operator>>` in the header, so that they match the implementation.

---

As a note and as already mentioned in the comments: Your other operator-overloads should return `Complex &` or `Complex` *not* `Complex *`. Take a look at [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) or [this page, detailing operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) to see what the canoncial implementations look like.